# for my loss function i give the errer: ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I wrote below loss function:

```
def custom_loss(q_k):
  def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    loss= y_true * y_true /np.log(y_pred + q_k)

  return loss
```

and I give the error:

```
Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (2nd_target:0) to a NumPy array
```

then according to @Dr.snoopy and @Kaveh, i edit my loss function but I got a new error, my new loss function:

```
def custom_loss(q_k):
  def loss(y_true,y_pred):
     return y_true * y_true /tf.math.log(y_pred + q_k)
 
  # Return a function
  return loss
```

and I should say `y_true` and `q_k` are tensor.

but I get the error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:789 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:143 __call__
        losses, sample_weight, reduction=self._get_reduction())
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/losses_utils.py:308 compute_weighted_loss
        losses = tf.convert_to_tensor(losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1431 convert_to_tensor_v2_with_dispatch
        value, dtype=dtype, dtype_hint=dtype_hint, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1441 convert_to_tensor_v2
        as_ref=False)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py:163 wrapped
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1566 convert_to_tensor
        ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:346 _constant_tensor_conversion_function
        return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:272 constant
        allow_broadcast=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:290 _constant_impl
        allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py:445 make_tensor_proto
        raise ValueError("None values not supported.")

    ValueError: None values not supported.
```

Code[image]

Update:

Thanks to @ Matthias Fripp, I edited my loss to :

```
    def custom_loss(q_k):
       def loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
           return y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred + q_k)               
       return loss_func
```

but i get new error:
InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
[[node gradient_tape/loss/mul/Mul (defined at :1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2026]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: You cannot implement a loss in numpy, it has to be with keras.backend functions.

Comment: thanks, yes I edit and I got a new error, None values not supported!

Comment: In your own words, what does it mean to return a value from a function? In your own words, what do you expect to be `return`ed when the function `def loss(y_true,y_pred):` is called? Why? In your own words, is there a `return` statement inside that function? Is the line `loss= y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred + q_k)` intended to compute the return value? If so, why are you expecting it to be returned?

Comment: with Keras backend and tf.math log both I got None values not supported error!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want a vector q_k to add to my y_pred and then kullback libler divergence would be the probability difference between y_true and y_pred + q_k.

Comment: for each function as loss  i get the same error, for example I replace a simple sum function, loss= y_true + y_pred+ q_k, but again i received the same error.

Comment: In your `loss` function, you need to return the value, not just calculate it. When a function doesn't have a `return` statement, it automatically returns `None`. Adding `return loss` inside the `loss` function should fix it. You may also want to use a name other than `loss` inside the `loss` function, since it's a little confusing to use the same name for two things.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasFripp, but I received a new error : InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
  [[node gradient_tape/loss/mul/Mul (defined at <ipython-input-34-b25a60fb0cdc>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2026]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: Glad I could help a bit. Since your question has changed now, you may want to tighten it up into a [minimum verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it as a new question.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp, thanks, i asked question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68944131/the-error-invalidargumenterror-required-broadcastable-shapes-in-keras

Answer (score 3):

You can not use numpy array in a loss function, since it will be executed in the graph mode.

Instead use tensorflow methods like this:

```
def custom_loss(q_k):

  def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return y_true * tf.math.log(y_pred + q_k) #tf.math.log instead of np.log
 
  # Return a function
  return loss
```

Comment: Thanks. but I get none! I update my question, please look at it and give me your idea.

Comment: Please never change the question completely, because it makes the answers worthless, and add new errors as new question or add it to your current question as a UPDATE section.

Comment: @شیواپاساراد In which line do you get the error? Please share complete error message.

Comment: thank you, @Kaveh for your suggestion about how to update my question. I share complete error.

Comment: @شیواپاساراد As @MatthiasFripp indicates, you should return computed value in `loss` function.

Comment: Yes i did and previous error is solved but I got new error:  InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
  [[node gradient_tape/loss/mul/Mul (defined at <ipython-input-34-b25a60fb0cdc>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_2026]

Function call stack:
train_function

Comment: What is the shape of `x` and `y` which you pass to `model.fit()`?

Comment: both are TensorShape([17105, 19])

Comment: I ran your code with the mentioned shape, and it is executed with no problem. Last guess: What is `q_k`? and what is the shape?

Comment: q_k is a sum distribution of the k element of the input. imagine I have N total input element, what I want is a prediction of the model together with a subset of N, for example, k, have same distribution compared to N. q_k is tensor and the shape is : TensorShape([17105, 19])

Comment: That's the problem. If you don't specify `batch_size` it will consider it as 32. Then it will compute at first (32,19) samples. So, the shape of `y_true` and `y_pred` is (32,19). But you have passed `q_k` with the shape (17105,19), which can not add a tensor with shape `(32,19)` and `(17105,19)`.

Comment: Thanks! it works, I specify batch_size= len(x_train), no error!! but if I want a batch_size size smaller than it, do you know how can I handle q_k?

Comment: Then you should somehow split `q_k` in the loss function based on the steps and epochs you are running.